# Flutter doctor Unable to determine Android Studio version in Mac - 2 android studio installed

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

When I do Flutter Doctor I get this error -
`Unable to determine Android Studio version.`

I have installed 2 Android studios side by side to get the canary channel features as well

- **Stable channel** - Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
- **Canary Channel** - Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 18

Here is the whole Doctor summary

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)            
[✓] Network resources
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Flutter Doctor has issues parsing preview versions of Android Studio.

You can see it in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135662), which has been opened quite recently and has been marked as duplicate due to this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121925).

The last comment there (**from two days ago**) states that this shouldn't block you from doing any Flutter development on your device.